# Is the row space of a matrix A a subspace A? If so, what are the objects of A?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, terminology

I have problems with an assertion that I read in a definition of the row space. 
I hope somebody can help me :)

This part is clear:
Let A be a mxn-matrix, with rows $ r_{1},...,r_{m} \in K^{n}  $  The set of all possible linear combinations of $ r_{1},...,r_{m}  $ is the row space of A.
Also the row space is a subspace of $K^{n}$.

My Problem:

In one definition that I have read it is stated that the row space of A is also a subspace of A. So the **concrete** Matrix A has to be a vector space. What are the objects of A?

Can somebody give me an interpretation of what it **exactly** means that the  row space of A is a subspace of A?

PS: I'm not used to write about math in english, please ask if something doesn't makes sense to you.

Comment: The phrase "subspace of $A$" is simply nonsense. Does the reference use **exactly**  those words? If not you should tell us exactly what it does say - possibly you're misinterpreting or mistranslating sommething.

Comment: sry, I pressed "enter" too soon. The comment I wanted to post:  I'm pretty sure that I translated "subspace of A" correctly but it seems like they(my source) made a mistake. I'm already satisfied with the answers (and your comment). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix is not a vector space.  Generally,  it represents a linear transformation,  from one vector space to another.

Now, since the number of columns always equals the dimension of the domain space, we can view the row space as a subspace of $V$ (where $T:V\to W$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)                                                                                    If  $f:V\rightarrow W $ is a linear transformation and I search for the transformation matrix A of f. Let $ B_{1}=\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$ be the basis of V and $ B_{2}=\{w_{1},...,w_{m}\} $ of W, then $f(v_{1})=w=a_{11}w_{1}+...+a_{m1}w_{m}$ with $a_{11},..,a_{m1}$ representing the elements of the first column of A. So if we continue we get n columns which is the dimension of the domain space V, but why should (for example) always $(a_{11},...,a_{1n})^{T}\in V$ be true ?

Comment: It's always an $n$-tuple, of elements from the field, so it can be viewed as such.

Comment: Why is it always an n-tuple of elements from the field? If you aren't in the mood to explain it, I would also be happy about a link to a good explanation :)

Comment: I was just thinking I might refer you to Paul Halmos' book _Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces_.   The reason though,  that it's an $n$-tuple, where $n=\operatorname{dim}V$, is simply that matrix multiplication won't work otherwise.   Try a few examples.

Comment: I think that I understand it now, thank you again :) I will check if the book is availible in the library from my university. I think it would be good for my development to also read english literature about math.

Comment: Ok.  There is a subtlety (i think) underlying this.  You correctly noted in your question that the row space is a subspace of $K^n$, where $K$ is the underlying field.   One thing you will learn is that all finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.   With this, the row space can be viewed as, at least, isomorphic to a subspace of $V$.  So, in general,  we might need an isomorphism.   But in many examples $V$ is just $\Bbb K^n$ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, a matrix is **not** a vector space. Asserting that the row space of a matrix is a subspace of that matrix is just an abuse of language.